# Is is possible to read a .csv file with Javascript fetch API?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Like

```
fetch('state_wise_data.csv')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Tried doing this but didn't work.

Comment: When it said `enter code here` you were supposed to enter code there.

Comment: "didn't work". What happened, what didn't happen? Did you expect `response.json()` to do something sensible with data that's not JSON?

Comment: at the moment you are missing a  `'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Will do that for future queries. Kinda getting used to stackoverflow. Thank you

Comment: You can't load CSV with `response.json())`, you need to use something like `response.text())`

Comment: @KiraLT Thanks for your response. In that case, after getting the response, am I supposed to convert that data into array and use it?

Answer (score 13):

First of all, `CSV` it's not a `JSON`. Fetch does not have CSV support, you will need to download CSV string (you can use [response.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text)) and use the third party CSV parser.

For parse CSV parser you can use [papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/):

> "Isn't parsing CSV just String.split(',')?"
>
> Heavens, no. Papa does it right. Just pass in the CSV string with an optional configuration.

Example:

```js
const response = fetch('state_wise_data.csv')
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(v => Papa.parse(v))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))

response.then(v => console.log(v))
```

It also supports file downloading:

```js
Papa.parse('state_wise_data.csv', {
    download: true,
    complete: results => {
        console.log(results);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Fetch is 100% work with .csv file (or even api with req.query).
'content-type': 'text/csv' must be addressed in the fetch's headers:{}, and use res.text() instead of res.json() to interpret data.

```
const downloadCsv = async () => {
    try {
        const target = `https://SOME_DOMAIN.com/data/csv/addresses.csv`; //file
        //const target = `https://SOME_DOMAIN.com/api/data/log_csv?$"queryString"`; //target can also be api with req.query
        
        const res = await fetch(target, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8',
                //'Authorization': //in case you need authorisation
            }
        });

        if (res.status === 200) {

            const data = await res.text();
            console.log(data);

        } else {
            console.log(`Error code ${res.status}`);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

pretty easy,

GET the url, with normal fetch req, and first convert response to text and then it's done

```js
fetch('sample-url.csv')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is not a JSON file type, so you cant parse as a json text. you can check how to parse CSV text in javascript here : [Example JavaScript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following method and insert it where you are supposed console.log the data.

```js
const parseCSV = (data) => {
  // create empty array
  const csvData = [];
  
  // this will return each line as an individual String
  const lines = data.split("\n");
  
  // loop through the lines and return an array of individual   
  // Strings within the line that are separated by a comma
  
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      csvData[i] = lines[i].split(",");
  }
  
  // return an array of arrays 2D array
  // e.g [ [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8] ]
  return csvData;
};
```

Comment: You have a syntax error: `csvData[]` ->  `csvData = []`

Comment: Ahhh you are right my friend, thanks for spotting it!